# Issue sorting enumerated list by position

Tags: python

I'm having some difficulty sorting my enumerated list by position.

I've searched other posts, and I think it could be because the values are not converted to integers.

However, I'm not sure how to do that in this context.

For example:

```
lst = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'grey', 'brown', 'violet']
```

Then I enumerate the list:

```
lst_pos = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst)]
```

The result is:

```
 >>> ['0, blue', '1, red', '2, green', '3, black', '4, yellow', '5, orange', '6, purple', '7, white', '8, grey', '9, brown', '10, violet']
```

Then I sort lst_pos:

```
lst_sort = sorted(lst_pos, key = lambda x:x[0])
```

The value of lst_sort is:

```
>>> ['0, blue', '1, red', '10, violet', '2, green', '3, black', '4, yellow', '5, orange', '6, purple', '7, white', '8, grey', '9, brown']
```

This issue is that `violet` is appearing before `green`.

Apologies if this explanation is lengthy, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your lambda just take the first character of the string? Then 10 from violet would be 1, and the order is correct?

Comment: why do you want to sort a list that is already sorted like you want? note that sort sort strings, and 10 comes before 2 as a string

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this was just an example scenario. What I'm actually doing is taking the difference between two large lists and printing their original positions to sort by.

Comment: That's not the usual way to enumerate a list. Usually we enumerate the list as tuples (index, value), not strings `f"{i}, {v}"`. Strings are less flexible to sort than tuples (exactly like you found out, for example because they sort numbers in string order rather than numeric order). Trust me, enumerating as a string `f"{i}, {v}"` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: teddygraham: if you simply want to string-insert the position like that, then use a list comprehension [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst)] as-is, don't re-sort the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `lst`:

```
lst =  ['0, blue', '1, red', '10, violet', '2, green', '3, black', '4, yellow', '5, orange', '6, purple', '7, white', '8, grey', '9, brown']
```

sort by the first element of string (which is each element of the `lst`):

```
lst_sort = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: int(x.split(', ')[0]))
```

result:

```
['0, blue',
 '1, red',
 '2, green',
 '3, black',
 '4, yellow',
 '5, orange',
 '6, purple',
 '7, white',
 '8, grey',
 '9, brown',
 '10, violet']
```

Note first element of string needs to be converted to `int` to ensure proper order of sorting.

Comment: so your sort method does nothing in this case, because the input list is already sorted.

Comment: It was sorting but in a very optimistic scenario :-) I've changed order of `lst` to show it is indeed sorting.

Comment: This actually produced the results I was looking for, thank you! Also sorry if my explanation/understanding of what's going on is limited.

Answer (score 1):

One way to to create a list of tuples, not a list of strings.  The list comprehension that creates `lst_pos` becomes:

```
lst_pos = [(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(lst)]
lst_sort = sorted(lst_pos, key = lambda x:x[0])
lst_sort

[(0, 'blue'),
 (1, 'red'),
 (2, 'green'),
 (3, 'black'),
 (4, 'yellow'),
 (5, 'orange'),
 (6, 'purple'),
 (7, 'white'),
 (8, 'grey'),
 (9, 'brown'),
 (10, 'violet')]
```

Comment: Good idea. You can simplify it, though. Eg, `lst_pos = list(enumerate(lst))`. And you don't actually need a key function here. When 2 tuples are compared they're compared item by item until a mismatch occurs, and that's guaranteed to happen on the 1st items because the integers are all unique. (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations for further details).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the index 2x. Once for your string and a second time as integer.
Create a tuple starting with the index and the second value is your string.
Then sort by the integer index which is stored in the tuple x[0]. After the sorting remove the integer index. This way you have your sorted strings.

```
lst = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'grey', 'brown', 'violet']
lst = [(i, f"{i}, {v}") for i, v in enumerate(lst)]
lst_sort = sorted(lst, key = lambda x:x[0])
lst_sort = [x[1] for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though the key isn't being sorted numerically, which is why 10 appearing after 1 but before 2, as it reads 1, 1-0, 2